# Count all vowels in 2D string

Tags: c, string, count, 2d

Hello so I´ve tried to count all vowels in my 2D string. And my program keeps giving me wrong output and I don´t know what´s wrong.
This is my code :

```
int main() {
    char strings[3][50] = { "hello WORLD", "hELLO", "Hello" };
    printf("%d \n", vowels_count_2D(3, 50, strings));

    return 0;
}

int vowels_count_2D(const int rows, const int cols, char string[][cols]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int vowels = string[i][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (string[i][j] == 'a' || string[i][j] == 'e' ||
                string[i][j] == 'i' || string[i][j] == 'o' ||
                string[i][j] == 'u' || string[i][j] == 'A' ||
                string[i][j] == 'E' || string[i][j] == 'I' ||
                string[i][j] == 'O' || string[i][j] == 'U') {
                vowels++;
            }
        }
        return vowels;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output should be `7`.
My output is `107`. Why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: When `i` is `0` you do `int vowels = string[0][0];` ... or `int vowels = 'h';` ... Apparently your computer is ASCII based because `'h' /*ASCII 'h' is 104*/ + 3` is `107` and you return that value without looping for `i` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop logic is incorrect: `vowels` should be initialized to `0` outside the outer loop and the `return vowels;` statement moved outside the loop body.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int vowels_count_2D(const int rows, const int cols, const char string[][cols]) {
    int vowels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            if (string[i][j] == 'a' || string[i][j] == 'e' ||
                string[i][j] == 'i' || string[i][j] == 'o' ||
                string[i][j] == 'u' || string[i][j] == 'A' ||
                string[i][j] == 'E' || string[i][j] == 'I' ||
                string[i][j] == 'O' || string[i][j] == 'U') {
                vowels++;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}

int main() {
    char strings[3][50] = { "hello WORLD", "hELLO", "Hello" };
    printf("%d\n", vowels_count_2D(3, 50, strings));
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of scanning the full 2D array, you should probably stop at the null terminator or each string:

```
#include <string.h>

int vowels_count_2D(const int rows, const int cols, char string[][cols]) {
    int vowels = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols && string[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", string[i][j])) {
                vowels++;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My output is 107. Why?

You count only one row (due to premature `return vowels`) but start from ASCII value of `h`. You should set that `vowels` counter to `0`.

```
int vowels_count_2D(int rows, int cols,char string[][cols]) {
    int vowels = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {

        printf("V: %d\n", vowels);

        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++) {
            if(string[i][j] =='a'|| string[i][j]=='e'||string[i][j]=='i'||string[i]
            [j]=='o'||string[i][j]=='u'||string[i][j]=='A'||string[i][j]=='E'||string[i]
            [j]=='I'||string[i][j]=='O' ||string[i][j]=='U' )
            {
                vowels++;
            }
        }
    }
    return vowels;
}
```